# Doctrine 2: OneToMany Relation, order by foreign key

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sql-order-by, one-to-many

I have three entities (`Profile`, `ProfileValue` and `Value`).
A `Profile` has a one-to-many relation with `ProfileValue`, which has a many-to-one relation with the `Value` entity.

Is it possible to get the rleated `ProfileValues` from the `Profile`, ordered by the `value id`?

If I add the `orderby` annotation for a non-foreign-key like the enabled field in `ProfileValue`, it works. But for a foreign key, it failed with the message *`"inrecognized field"`*. Any ideas?

```php
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="profile")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Profile {

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var array $profileCValues
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ABC\XYZBundle\Entity\ProfileValue", mappedBy="profile", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"value" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $profileValues;
```

And here is the `ProfileValue` entity:

```php
/**
 * ABC\XYZBundle\Entity\ProfileValue
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="profile_value", indexes={@ORM\Index(columns={"profile_id"}), @ORM\Index(columns={"value_id"}) })
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ProfileValue {
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer $enabled
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="enabled", type="boolean", length=1, nullable=true)
     */
    private $enabled;

    /**
     * @var ABC\XYZBundle\Entity\Profile
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ABC\XYZBundle\Entity\Profile", inversedBy="profileValues")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="profile_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $profile;

    /**
     * @var ABC\XYZBundle\Entity\Value
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ABC\XYZBundle\Entity\Value")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="value_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $value;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am also looking to do thise

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem and solved it by adding a new field with foreign key:

```
/**
 * @var integer $valueId
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="value_id", type="integer")
 */
private $valueId;
```

Then you can order it without problems:

```
/**
 * @var array $profileCValues
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ABC\XYZBundle\Entity\ProfileValue", mappedBy="profile", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"valueId" = "ASC"})
 */
private $profileValues;
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
/**
 * @var array $profileCValues
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ABC\XYZBundle\Entity\ProfileValue", mappedBy="profile", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"id" = "ASC"})
 */
private $profileValues;
```

I don't use XML but this works in YML:

```
oneToMany:
  foos:
    targetEntity:             Company\ProjectBundle\Entity\Foo
    mappedBy:                 bar
    orderBy:                  { 'id': ASC }
```